# How can I run a command line app in C# and redirect/display its standard output while preserving the colors from the app?

Tags: c#, git

I am calling git via a command line in C#:

```cs
var logger = CreateProcess("git", $"log -n 1 {branchName}");
// some more code here
Console.WriteLine(logger.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

```cs
private static Process CreateProcess(string exe, string args)
{
    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = exe;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    return p;
}
```

However the colors that are normally displayed by the command line git app are not displayed when I later go to write the redirected output ot the console; everything is white instead. Is there any way to run the app and redirect the output without losing the colors?

Answer (score 1):

```
git -c color.ui=always log
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorui .

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this was a git issue rather than a .NET issue! But when I run that command, I just get the help documentation for git; is something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the word "log" in your answer for some reason; it just got cut off after "always" and I thought it was a command to set a global setting rather than an extra parameter for the `log` command!

Comment: I didn't write `log` in the answer to stress only the most relevant part of the command. Should I update the answer?

Comment: Yes, that would help, please. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it looks like this option is not working; when I run my program that is displaying the output of git, it gets turned into plain white on black text.

Comment: That's strange but I cannot test on Windows. On Linux works fine with any redirection.